# angular-gettext doesn't work despit displaying no erroe

Tags: angular, gruntjs, angular-gettext, grunt-angular-gettext

I started a new Angular project for a local company three days ago and they told me today that they wanted their web application to be in French AND in English.

So I found the [angular-gettext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-gettext) module which seemed to be a good solution.

I followed their [official tutorial](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/install/) (using Grunt) and despite some difficulties I found the way to have no error....But it still doesn't work for me !

I put some text in the `index.html` file with the `translate` directive in order to test my configuration. In fact this file will not contain anything excepted the `<app-root></app-root>` balise.

So let's begin by my `Gruntfile.js` and its two tasks :

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    nggettext_extract: {
      pot: {
        files: {
          'po/template.pot': ['src/*.html'] // the index.html file is here
        }
      },
    },

    nggettext_compile: {
      all: {
        options: {
          module: 'myApp'
        },
        files: {
          'src/js/translations.js': ['po/*.po']
        }
      },
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-angular-gettext');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('extract', ['nggettext_extract']);
  grunt.registerTask('extract', ['nggettext_compile']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', []);
};
```

I declared `myApp` module in an `app.js` file with the following code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [gettext]);

app.run(function (gettextCatalog) {
  gettextCatalog.setCurrentLanguage('fr');
});
```

So when I run my `grunt nggettext_extract` and `grunt nggettext_compile` command everything is ok, I have my `po folder` with my `template.pot` file and my `js folder` with my `translations.js` file. I made the translation using `poedit software` and the result is my `fr.po` file.

Here is my `translations.js` file that was generated :

```js
angular.module('myApp').run(['gettextCatalog', function (gettextCatalog) {
  /* jshint -W100 */
  gettextCatalog.setStrings('fr', {"Welcome ladies and gentleman":"Messieurs et Mesdames bienvenues","Welcome to the test zone":"Bienvenue dans la zone de test"});
  /* jshint +W100 */
}]);
```

The tutorial wanted me to add my `<script>` in the `index.html` file but using `angular-cli` I added them in my `angular-cli.json` file :

```json
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
    "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
    "../node_modules/angular-gettext/dist/angular-gettext.min.js",
    "./js/translations.js",
    "./app.js"
  ],
```

So for me I did everything and my sentences should be in French and not in English but it doesn't work...If you could help me it would be great !

Answer (score 0):

Angular-gettext is for AngularJS (ie. 1.x), doesn't work with Angular (ie. 2+). NG and angular-cli has awesome built-in i18n support, see: https://angular.io/guide/i18n